# If a programming language compiles to Java 8 bytecode, can it also run on Android?

Tags: java, android, java-8, jvm, programming-languages

I am creating a JVM language called Crypt which compiles to Java 8 bytecode. My question is, if this language can compile to Java 8 bytecode, and Java 8 bytecode runs on Android, can my language code also run on Android*?

*I've searched the internet and the best I could find was that you could load any Java library to Android if it was built using Java 8. Kotlin can run on Android but I don't know whether it was from the beginning or because Google provides first-class support for Kotlin on Android.

Comment: "and Java 8 bytecode runs on Android" -- Java 8 bytecode does not run on Android. Android uses Dalvik bytecode, as packaged in DEX files in the APK. All Java 8 bytecode needs to be cross-compiled into Dalvik bytecode. "Kotlin can run on Android" -- Kotlin source code gets compiled into bytecode. I forget whether presently that is a direct compilation to Dalvik bytecode or whether it still goes through the Java bytecode -> Dalvik bytecode conversion process. If you follow the patterns set by Kotlin, Scala, and other JVM languages that work with the Android build process, you should be OK.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I presumed that Android could run java bytecode because JVM languages are the only languages used for the creation of Android mobile apps (with the exception of C++). I could probably add a compiler option to convert the Java 8 bytecode to Dalvik bytecode.

Comment: @CommonsWare that should be an answer

Comment: I've been doing some more digging around and found this article on medium that clearly explains the compilation process for an android application made with java/kotlin code. This could be useful:  https://medium.com/@banmarkovic/process-of-compiling-android-app-with-java-kotlin-code-27edcfcce616